# Running Weinre bound to something other than localhost

Tags: android, weinre

I'm trying to setup Weinre according to the official manual [0].

I got stuck on this step:
Running the debug server bound to something other than localhost

I was able to run the debug server on `http://192.168.1.7:8080/` which is the IP address of my desktop.

But the server on address `http://192.168.1.7:8080/` is not accessible from the mobile phone.

Both desktop and mobile are on the same local network. What else needs to be set up to make it work?

[0] http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Running.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems getting network connectivity, it's usually better to use a version of weinre running on the public internet.  Here's some [instructions to run weinre on Heroku](http://pmuellr.blogspot.com/2012/11/weinre-installable-at-heroku-and-behind.html).  I also run a public weinre server at http://weinre.mybluemix.net/